# How to use Prisma 2 with Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, prisma

I am using Docker with Prisma for the first time. As we all know, [prisma 2](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/releases/tag/2.0.0-beta.3) has been out and I'd like to use it in my local Docker setup. Turns out I have no idea how.

In my `docker-compose.yml` the initial setup is (shortened):

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.34
```

I had no luck changing the version to 2:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:2
```

Specifying `2.0.0-beta.2` also didn't work : `ERROR: manifest for prismagraphql/prisma:2 not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`.

Also, I updated MySQL to v8:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8
```

Will that be a problem?

How do I setup my docker image using Prisma 2?

Answer (score 4):

There is no `prismagraphql/prisma:2` image available on the [docker hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/prismagraphql/prisma/tags?page=1&ordering=name&name=2).

On this [github issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/164) they say that:

> We are releasing Prisma 2 as a library rather than a server. So you will use it as just another dependency for your application. So you will create a docker image just like for another node app

This [open issue](https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/400) might help and this [recent tutorial to build a docker image using prisma 2](https://medium.com/@emilefugulin/building-a-sane-docker-image-for-typescript-lerna-and-prisma-2-76d8ff9926e4) should help you too.